# Angularjs - Check if user is leaving app, not just changing routes

Tags: angularjs, events, event-handling

I need to check if a user leaves the page but goes anywhere that isn't a route in my app, so I can track this user is really leaving. `$locationChangeStart` is triggered only when the user really goes to another route, so it doesn't look to work for my needs. `onbeforeunload` does not return whether the user is changing routes or leaving the app.